# Доступ к объектам Access можно получить только через Interop?

Tags: c#, .net, access, com, office

Например, мне нужно получить список модулей в Access, добавить какой-нибудь новый QueryDef .

Я могу это сделать иначе, не использую Interop?

Comment: ADO ODBC пробовали? Список поставщиков данных и возможности работать с Access можно посмотреть тут https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/a6cd7c08(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Если нужен доступ не только к данным, то, скорее всего, только интероп